# list registered XML schemas in DB2 for IBM i

Tags: sql, xml, db2, ibm-midrange

I've found  the documentation for adding and removing XML schemas to/from XML schema repository in DB2 for IBM i (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasp/rzaspxml2720.htm).

I haven't found any hints as to how to query XML schema repository to check what is already registered.

I've found an article on DeveloperWorks (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-validenv1/) that points to the  SYSCAT.XSROBJECTS table, but this refers to DB2 for LUW and such an object doesn't exist in DB2 on IBM i 7.1 (executing "select * from SYSCAT.XSROBJECTS" results in "XSROBJECTS in SYSCAT type *FILE not found").

I am sure there is a similar system table on IBM i, just can't find any reference to the proper name of that table at the moment.

Anyone can help with a way to query XML schema repository for the list of registered schemas (preferably using SQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IBM i one needs to use QSYS2 database schema to access XSROBJECTS catalog view.
So the query used to list registered schemas may look like.

```
select * from QSYS2.XSROBJECTS
```

For further reference you can check https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcatalogtbls.htm

A comprehensive list of IBM DB2 for i catalogue views, and services can be found at

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/techupdates/db2/landscape

Comment: Additional schema objects exist, and locations can be identified with [IBM DB2 for i Catalogs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/techupdates/db2/landscape) PDF. Suggest editing answer to add.

Comment: @user2338816 Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the answer.